# Android black-box UI testing

Tags: android, automated-tests, android-testing, ui-testing

I have following problem:
I need to test app as blackbox app on different devices.

I've tried to use `monkeyrunner` for it, but it so long to change tap coordinates for each device.

`Robotium` and `Robolectric` - useless  cause I  need to test app as black box, and they are `Juint` based.

`uiautomatorviewer` - useless too, because i have specific android image without uiautomator  on board. Probably easiest solution it's to add it on device, but for now I can't do it.

Can anybody help me which tool should I use.

What I need:
1) Parse xml structure of apk.
2) Be able to tap by this structure.
3) Be able to copy data to clipboard.
4) Be able to take screenshots.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to go with **Robotium**.
It will allow you to even take the screenshots.
It is even easy to write testcases Using Robotium.
It provides `SOLO` class with lots of functionality for blackbox testing.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should go for Robotium only as it is most suitable and also 
recommended for black-box testing. Go through this once - http://code.google.com/p/robotium/